# Imaginary number

Tags: number-theory, complex-numbers

In the universe of numbers. Is the square root of negative one the only imaginary number or there exist some more? If more, what are they called? Thank you for the response.

Comment: Observe that if $i^2=-1$, then also $(-i)^2=-1$.

Comment: The most common sense of the phrase "imaginary numbers" is the set of numbers of the form $ki$, where $i^2=-1$ and $k$ is a real number. In this sense then, there are infinitely many imaginary numbers.

Answer (score 3):

They are called **Complex Numbers**.

If you have a number $i $ with $i^2=-1$, you can also think of $2i $, $i/3$, etc. These are called *imaginary numbers*, probably because their squares are negative reals. The name doesn't make a lot of sense, but it has stuck historically.

Now, with numbers you want to add them and multiply them. As squares of imaginary are real, you may also add a real number. That way you form the complex numbers, which are all numbers of the form $a+bi $, with $a,b $ real numbers.

Comment: There are also things called the quaternions, the octonions, the sedonions, but the complex numbers are all most of us ever need.

Comment: Good point. I don't like to highlight quaternions because I have witnessed an industry of publishing papers that extend, mostly in a trivial way, usual results in complex numbers.

Comment: Just be be clear, you're saying that an imaginary number is a real multiple of $i$ and that any complex number is the sum of a real number and an imaginary number; is that right? It seems people often introduce the imaginary number $i$ and then jump directly into the complex numbers, I suppose because there's not very much you can do with just imaginaries and reals.

Comment: @DavidK: the point with numbers is that you want to be able to add them and multiply. A set that contains the imaginary numbers and where you can multiply numbers, necessarily contains the reals. If you also want addition, you end up with all the complex numbers.

Comment: @DavidK Yes, what you said after "just to be clear" is right.

Comment: @MartinArgerami You could have a set of numbers on which addition is closed but multiplication is not. I think you are saying that it is not very interesting to work only with the pure imaginary numbers in this fashion, and I agree. Personally I think the real numbers are interesting, and it is interesting to adjoin $i$ to the reals, at which point you already have the complex numbers. The definition of "imaginary numbers" is a relatively uninteresting thing, I think, but I recognize that some people are sticklers for it.

Comment: Thank you for the comments and answers ...but are not all these complex numbers again the family of square root of -1, so called 'i'? I wanted to ask if there are some imaginary numbers independent of square root of -1? Thank you

Comment: @jpara: in that case, I think you will have to be more specific as what you mean by "number", by "imaginary", and by "independent".

Answer (score 1):

There are different types of imaginary numbers. Complex numbers are numbers of the form $z=a+ib$. Imaginary numbers are known as quaternions.

They satisfy:

$i^2=j^2=k^2=ijk=-1$

Here is a table that might help you understand:

[image]

Comment: "Imaginary numbers are known as quaternions." Not necessarily. You could consider only complex numbers of the form $0+ib$ and call those the set of "imaginary numbers." (I think that's actually the most commonly used sense of that term.)

Comment: Thank you for the response Aleksander, it is interesting to know about all these family of numbers.